# Binding data to django model formsets

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

Im using Django and a model formset. Its a pretty basic model of a multiple choice question. The form to create a question successfully uses a model formset combined with a regular form - the regular form for the question and the formset for the possible answers. This part is working.

However, how can create an 'Edit' version of this? I want to query back the answers I currently have saved for the given question and bind these to a form each in the formset.

Thanks, Mike

The Models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(...)
  text = models.TextField(...)
  time_allowed = models.DecimalField(...)

class Answer(models.Model):
  uuid = models.CharField(...)
  question = models.ForeignKey(QuestionDetail, ...)
  text = models.TextField()
  weight = models.DecimalField(...)
```

The Forms:

```
class QuestionModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  required_css_class = 'required'
  class Meta:
    model = QuestionDetail
    widgets = {
      'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'class': 'question-text'})
    }    

class AnswerModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  required_css_class = 'required'
  class Meta:
    widgets = {
      'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': '3', 'class': 'question-text'}),
      'weight': forms.TextInput(attrs={'maxlength':'5', 'class': 'question-weight'}),
    }    

class BaseAnswerFormSet(BaseFormSet):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BaseAnswerFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Must have at least two answers.
    self.forms[0].empty_permitted = False
    self.forms[1].empty_permitted = False    

AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer, formset=BaseAnswerFormSet, form=AnswerModelForm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `queryset` keyword argument:

```
answers_qs = my_question.answer_set
AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer,
                                     formset=BaseAnswerFormSet,
                                     form=AnswerModelForm,
                                     queryset=answers_qs)
```